# Can i have alertDialogBox inside another alertDialogbox

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Suppose in my application, i want the user to enter his roll no in a alertDialogbox that appears and then may be another alertDialogbox appears which will ask for his name...
If both the enterd values are correct, he is allowed to do a specific task else not.
How should i implement it?
i tried creating two alertboxes one inside other (i mean, on the click of the ok button), but that did not worked,i got an error message.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);               
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);              

        alert1.setTitle("Please Enter Roll No");
        alert1.setView(input);
        alert1.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());               
                final EditText input1 = new EditText(getBaseContext());             

                alert2.setTitle("Please Enter Name");
                alert2.setView(input1);
                alert2.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
                });

                alert2.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                alert2.show(); 

                            }
        });

        alert1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        alert1.show();
```

How should i achieve it??
if there is some other way also, pl letme know...

Thank u!!

Comment: What error message? Show what you tried.

Comment: The error message is: Sorry the application closed unexpectedly. Please try again

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by having one 'inside' the other one. You can have the first one pop up and when they press the Enter button it, you can make it trigger the opening of a second one. But in that case the first one is going to close and then the second is going to open it won't be 'inside' of it. Post some of your code and maybe we can help you further with your specific situation.

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks to me like it should work the way you have it. On a side note: you should use getApplicationContext() instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: the error i got is: The error message is: Sorry the application closed unexpectedly. Please try again

Comment: Look in your logcat output and it will tell you what exception caused the app to close.

Comment: Sorry! i don't know logcat output, is it the console? There was no message displayed on the console

Comment: Nope not the console. In eclipse on the top bar press Window->Show View->other->Android->Logcat once the window is open it will show you some debug type output from your device.